# Remove input dimensions in a sklearn pipeline?

Tags: scikit-learn

I have the following pipeline in sklearn:

```
pipe = sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline(steps=[
    ('scalar', StandardScaler()),
    ('pca', utils.PCA(n_components=n_pca_components)),
    ('reduce',umap.UMAP(n_neighbors=umap_n_neighbors, min_dist=umap_min_dist, metric=umap_metric)),
    ('model',utils.DBSCAN(eps=dbscan_eps,min_samples=dbscan_min_samples)),    
])
```

Is there a simple way to eliminate one of the dimensions in the step between the pca and the umap?

So if my pca output is (0:100,0:10) and I want for example to remove the first channel before passing the data in the pipeline to the umap (0:100,1:10)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could potentially have an intermediate step between the two stages to achieve what you want with [FunctionTransformer](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.FunctionTransformer.html)

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import FunctionTransformer

def custom_function(x):
    # Add your code here

pipe = sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline(steps=[
    ('scalar', StandardScaler()),
    ('pca', utils.PCA(n_components=n_pca_components)),
    ('remove_dimension', FunctionTransformer(custom_function))
    ('reduce',umap.UMAP(n_neighbors=umap_n_neighbors, min_dist=umap_min_dist, metric=umap_metric)),
    ('model',utils.DBSCAN(eps=dbscan_eps,min_samples=dbscan_min_samples)),    
])
```